# Angular Standalone Template - VS2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022

I made a new project from Standalone Angular Template in Visual Studio 2022, but instead of having files in project i have single npm Item but no files are shown. What should i do with this ? Files for Angular project are created and they are inside folder, but they do not appear as project files.
[Project solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9evhP.png)

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxmfj.png)

Comment: So there's no "src" folder in the project?

Comment: Full Angular project is created, with node_modules and src and everything inside folder (using windows folder Explorer i can see them ), but they are not recognized as part of Standalone Angular Template. I quickly checked on my second laptop and it's the same so Microsoft must did something with Template

Answer (score 0):

When you export the .esproj project template in Visual Studio, the resulting MyTemplate.vstemplate **file is missing a required property, which causes the issue**.

*You need to add the below tag with a value true.*

`<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>`

> It specifies whether to create the project and perform parameter replacement in the specified location, or perform parameter replacement in a temporary location and then save the project to the specified location.

- By default, this value is true but better to add it as I observed it
  is not working with .esproj project.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/createinplace-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2022)